# Biztalk 2016 The transport channel detected a poison message.

Tags: biztalk, message-queue, msmq, biztalk-2016

I have a tool write a message to MSMQ, and a receive port (in Biztalk 2016) looks up on the queue and process the message.

But I get the following error:

```
The adapter "WCF-Custom" raised an error message. Details "System.ServiceModel.MsmqPoisonMessageException: The transport channel detected a poison message. This occurred because the message exceeded the maximum number of delivery attempts or because the channel detected a fundamental problem with the message. The inner exception may contain additional information.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqReceiveHelper.TryReceive(MsmqInputMessage msmqMessage, TimeSpan timeout, MsmqTransactionMode transactionMode, MsmqMessageProperty& property)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MsmqInputChannelBase.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelListener`1.SecurityInputChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.InputChannelBinder.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, RequestContext& requestContext)".
```

I have no idea how to solve or at least find out the root cause.
I tried to read the message in MSMQ, but it is encrypted.

Comment: Is there more to the exception stack.

Comment: Are there any warning or Errors in the Event Log at the time it tries to pick up the message?